# How to set height of one layout to another layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have one parent `LinearLayout` and inside it I have two child `LinearLayout`. I have 4 `TextView` in 1st child layout and 2 `TextView` in 2nd child layout. Parent layout has property `android:layout_height="wrap_content` as well as child layout too.

I want to set height of 1st child layout to 2nd child layout because 1st child layout has 4 textbox and 2nd child layout has to textbox.

I just want to adjust the height of 2nd child layout. I am putting my code below.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".8"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblBooking_Code"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblSession"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblCustomer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblMobile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblBooking_Gross_Amt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblBooking_PayAmt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblBooking_Balance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: give 2nd layout     android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: what you want `post your screenshot here ?`

Comment: @VishalYadav, I solved it.

Answer (score 2):

Make the height of 2nd child layout `"match_parent"`

Answer (score 0):

Making the height of 2nd child layout "match_parent" and implementing "weightSum=3" I achieved my requirement.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".8"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblBooking_Code"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblSession"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblCustomer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblMobile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".1"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblBooking_Gross_Amt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblBooking_PayAmt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblBooking_Balance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```